# Creating two clusters with as equal centroids as possible

Tags: r, partitioning

I have a number of data points that can be placed in a 2D-space according to two variables, in this case named "Variable_1" and "Variable_2", like so:

```
ID  |  Variable_1  |  Variable_2
--------------------------------------------
1   |  4.3522      |  5.2321
2   |  3.6423      |  6.3223
3   |  5.2331      |  3.2452
4   |  2.6334      |  7.3443
... |  ...         |  ...
```

Now, I would like to partition my data points into two, disjoint (that is, the two sets should have no elements in common), equal sized (I have an even number of data points) clusters where the centroids of the two clusters lies as close as possible to each other (it would be nice if I could find the optimal solution to this problem, but if that's not possible something that approximates the global optimum will do).

**Bonus request 1:** *Preferably*, I'd like to do this in R, since I'm already using this language for the project in question.

**Bonus request 2:** It would be even more nice if if would be possible to take the internal variances of the two clusters into account somehow as well. That is, while my *primary* goal is to get to clusters where the centroids are close to equal, I still don't want the internal variance in one of the clusters to significantly differ from the other. However, I realise that by introducing this aspect, you probably complicate matters quite a lot, so I'm willing to drop this wish if necessary.

Comment: One normally would not think of these as "clusters" or "partitions", which are typically *disjoint* (or nearly disjoint) subsets. Are you just trying to separate the data into two subsets with comparable first and second moments?  If so, are you also concerned about matching the mixed second moments (indicating the covariance)? Do you also want the *sizes* of these subsets to be approximately equal?  (If not, it's often easy to find solutions!)

Comment: @whuber Good questions! I've updated my question to indicate that I want two disjoint, equal sized clusters. And yes, I want comparable first and (if possible) second moments.

However, I'm not quite sure what "matching the mixed second moments" would entail.

Comment: It is difficult to conceive of the sense in which two subsets with common centroids and variances could possibly be "disjoint."  Those moment-matching criteria appear designed to make the subsets overlap as much as possible!  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @whuber I'm simply meaning that they shouldn't have any elements in common. Some context: These data points represents images and the variables represents scores on different measures. I'm going to use them for a psychology experiment with two different conditions, and I want to create a set for each condition that is as close to the other set as possible with respect to these scores (but I can't reuse images so I need to have two different sets).

Comment: It sounds like you want a support vector machine and the two closest support vectors.

Comment: Actually, based on your comment, what it _really_ sounds like you want is to generate a sample and then assign binary labels such that both classes have similar moments. I don't think it's right to call those "clusters," and I think this is a discrete sampling problem, not a clustering problem.

Comment: The task could be seen from matching point of view. If partition your set in two subsets, each point in one maximally similar (close) to its counterpart in the other, the two subsets will be maximally similar in total. This sort of matching is "Maximum Weighted Matching in General Graphs" (for example read [this](http://www.algorithmic-solutions.info/leda_guide/graph_algorithms/maximum_weighted_matching.html).

Comment: @ssdecontrol When I asked this question on Stack Overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635835/divide-a-dataset-into-two-clusters-with-equal-total-variances), I was told that the concept I should use to describe what I wanted to do was "clustering". Guess that wasn't the case then :P

Comment: @ttnphns That's interesting. I'm using the so-called Hungarian algorithm (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961493/finding-the-best-matching-pairwise-points-from-2-vectors/13963652#13963652) for matching my images on another place in my experiment (where data points from predefined subset 1 should be matched with data points from predefined subset 2). Sounds like the method you suggested should do the trick. Just need to find a good implementation of it in R.

Comment: Hungarian algorithm is for 2 sets (i.e. bipartite graph). For one set (general graph), the similar matching algo is Edmonds': http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3964/generalization-of-the-hungarian-algorithm-to-general-undirected-graphs. I think you need it, its weights-allowing version.

Comment: ...and I suspect you should do the job on the matrix of squared euclidean distances.

Comment: @ttnphns Your reformulation changes the problem. There is no assurance that the matching solution you propose will be optimal (although it shouldn't be too bad). However, it's also probably a better approach to obtaining what the OP actually wants, as opposed to optimizing the distance between centroids (which appears likely *not* to match second moments at all closely). Trumping all these considerations is the fact that such case-control procedures will make subsequent analysis problematic. We should be asking *why not just split the data randomly?*

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your input! "Trumping all these considerations is the fact that such case-control procedures will make subsequent analysis problematic." Why is that? "We should be asking why not just split the data randomly?" What if the data in the resulting two have really different centroids? This is a one-off partition that then will be used throughout several testing sessions.

Comment: When you use a guided deterministic method like the one you propose, you can match *some* characteristics of the data sets--in this case the centroids and variances--but there's no guarantee that they match in any other way. So, when your analysis finds a "significant" difference, *it's impossible to assign a cause to it*. It could be due to how your partitioning algorithm performed or it could be real *and you don't know which it is*.

Comment: @whuber The thing is, for all intense and purposes, my data points make up *the whole* population. The only thing I care about is that the centroids are as close to each other as possible. That is, my *only* concern is that I want these set of stimuli images to be as equal as possible on the variables specified. (I probably shouldn't have used the word "significant" before, since that implies that I'm doing some kind of inferential statistics on this data.)

Comment: I would venture to challenge the assumption that your data should be considered the entire population. That would mean you intend your experiment to apply *only* to the images in this study (as partitioned by your algorithm, yet) and never to any other images. Is that really the case? It would be a remarkably limited experiment! Regardless, you're still hampered by the other considerations I advanced: you will be unable to draw conclusions about the *people* in your study because any differences you observe could be attributed to differences in *the specific partition you created.*

Comment: @whuber This is a really interesting discussion (don't know if it should be moved to the chat though) and you make some good points! :) Yeah, I was probably off with the population thing (I tried to make another point before I really understood what you meant). If there's a greater risk that I might add some kind of bias between my two data sets using some deterministic method, I of course want to avoid it, which is why I might take your advice and just run with a random partition.

Comment: @whuber Problem is, it will only be a *single* randomisation that will be used for all subsequent trials, which is why I at least entertained the possibility that it might be more wise to use some deterministic method (in that case, at least I *know* that the values of the important variables that I hypothesize are important for the outcome aren’t unevenly distributed; if I use a random partition, I might get two data sets that definitely are unusable).